# How do I make multi-table update query everyday on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

I'm working on automating the process of building a database. This is a database that needs daily updates after one build.

This database has 51 tables, divided into 3 schemas (there are 17 tables in each schema), and has a total of 20 million records, each record with a PK of manage_number .

I need to update 2000~3000 records every day, but I don't know which method to use.

1. Make a table for PK indexing

This is a method to separately create a table with a PK and a table name with a PK in the same database. To create a table with metadata about which table the manage_number is stored in. Currently, this methodology is applied. The problem is that the build time takes 5-6 times longer than before (increased from 2 minutes to 12 minutes).

2. Multi-table update query

This is how to perform update query on 17 tables with the same schema. However, in this case, the load in the FROM clause is expected to be very high, and I think it will be a burden on the server.

Update query may looks like below.

```sql
UPDATE table1, table2, table3, ..., table17
SET data_here
WHERE manage_number = 'TARGET_NUMBER';
```

Please share which way is better, or if you have a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you changing one column of _every_ row in every table?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the tables.